# Counting number of voxels above threshold from a tiff stack

Tags: matlab, image-processing, tiff, imagej

I have uploaded a tiff stack into MATLAB and am trying to count the number of voxels within a certain threshold. The max values of the image is 0 to 255, and my threshold is 75 to 255. The image has been color separated so that it is now just red and black. My code is as follows,

```
FileTif='ImageStack.tif';
InfoImage=imfinfo(FileTif);
mImage=InfoImage(1).Width;
nImage=InfoImage(1).Height;
NumberImages=length(InfoImage);
FinalImage=zeros(nImage,mImage,NumberImages,'uint16');
for i=1:NumberImages
   FinalImage(:,:,i)=imread(FileTif,'Index',i,'Info',InfoImage);
end
idx = find(FinalImage >= 75 & FinalImage <= 255);
length(idx)
```

My question is whether or not this captures what I said I am trying to do. Or rather, when uploading a tiff stack in this fashion, are the elements of my 3D matrix FinalImage the color values ranging from 0 to 255? I am confident that I am correct as

```
max(FinalImage(:))
min(FinalImage(:))
```

returns 255 and 0 respectively, though confusion arises when I use a voxel counter plugin on ImageJ and get a different value. I am not sure if the discrepancy is due to the voxel counting method in the plugin or the way ImageJ thresholds the image stack. Any light shed on the discrepancy would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you initialize `FinalImage` as uint16 if the pixel intensities range from 0 to 255 (i.e. uint8)? Also what values do you get with imageJ?

Comment: I am not too familiar with the differences between uint8 and uint16 and am not sure when one is preferred over the other. I found sample code for loading a tiff stack into MATLAB and it used uint16. The value I got from my code in Matlab is 1469144 (tried with both uint16 and uint8 and got the same number) and ImageJ gave me the value 1136671

Comment: Ok. What is the plugin you used in ImageJ? The difference between uint8 and uint16 relates to the values pixels can have. With uint8, it's from 0 to 2^8 (i.e. 255) whereas with uint16 its 2^16 (i.e. 65535), so the range is much much bigger. I think ImageJ converts everything to uint8 for processing  (Check [here](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-28.html))

Comment: The plugin in ImageJ is [Voxel Counter](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/voxel-counter.html). It makes sense then that I got the same value for uint8 and uint16 in MATLAB, since the max value of the data was 255. I appreciate your help @Benoit_11

Comment: Alright glad to help! And thanks for the tip I did not know about the Voxel Counter plugin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem and am posting the answer here if anyone else needs it. I was clicking 'apply' after setting the threshold which would change it to binary and so lead to an erroneous result. If I set the threshold and then use the voxel counter plugin then I would get the same result as my code in MATLAB.